# Select one Table with different amount of Table Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select a table from my SQL database.
This table can have many different columns, as I'm putting together a dynamic query.

How can I rewrite my `fetch_array` to a dynamic number of columns?
Here is my current code:

```
$q = $db_object->query($query);
$returnstring = '';
while($r = $q->fetch_array()){
      $returnstring .= '<tr>';
      $returnstring .= '<td>'.$r.'</td>'; //Here can appear many different columns.
      $returnstring .= '</tr>'; 
}
```

In the query could e.g. two, three, four or more columns of the table show up.

Can I do a `foreach` or something like this?

Comment: u want single row but multiple columns??

Comment: you just need to measure the count of fields in the table (`count($r)`)?

Comment: No I want to select all rows but just single (or two,three) colums per query

Comment: The columns which you want is standard or are different per row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will make as many `td`s as the number of columns in your row.

```
$q = $db_object->query($query);
$returnstring = '';
while($r = $q->fetch_array()){
      $returnstring .= '<tr>';

      foreach($r as $key=>$value)
      {
        $returnstring .= '<td>'.$key.' : value='.$value.'</td>'; //Here can appear many different columns.
      }


      $returnstring .= '</tr>'; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats what im looking for... i dont know i cound do a foreach on a fetched array

Comment: `foreach` can be used on any array.

Comment: just be careful as the row may contain both int and string keys for single field

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky : Is it the best way to implement dynamic td ? I mean there's no sign of colspan for rows which have less columns.

Comment: @JA and lvil that is impossible. Any single query when returns a result does not have different columns in different rows. All the rows have same number of columns. By Dynamic the OP meant that number can change for some queries. Sometimes their query can return 4 columns sometimes 5 but for 1 result set number of columns remain same.